# Rails routing causing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, crud

I'm super new to Ruby/Rails and need help with an assignment I'm working on.  I'm supposed to add native advertising to Bloccit (project i'm working on for class) in the form of sponsored links. Any help would be very appreciated :)

What needs to be done:
1) Create a new model called Advertisement. It should have the following attributes: title:string, copy:text, price:integer.

2) Generate a controller for the new advertisement model with index and show actions. Should the controller class and file names have a singular (advertisement) or plural (advertisements) prefix? Be consistent with the naming pattern used for the posts controller class and file generated earlier.

3) Update routes.rb to use resourceful routing for Advertisement.

4) Complete the index and show actions in AdvertisementsController.

5) Update the Advertisement index and show views.

This is what I've got:

First thing, create model like so

```
rails g model Advertisements title:string, copy:text, price:integer
```

Then, create controller like so

```
rails g controller Advertisements index show
```

Resourceful routing:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :advertisement
  resources :posts 

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'

end
```

Index and show actions:

```
class AdvertisementController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @advertisements = Advertisement.all
  end

  def show
    @advertisements = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Index view:

```
<h1>Advertisements</h1>
<% @advertisements.each do |advertisement| %>
<% end %>
```

Show view:

```
<h1><%= @advertisements.title %></h1>
<p><%= @advertisements.copy %></p>
<p><%= @advertisements.price %></p>
```

When I go to localhost:3000/advertisement I see a blank page page with "Advertisements" at the top. When I go to to localhost:3000/advertisement/index I see an error message:

Couldn't find Advertisement with 'id'=index

```
  def show
    @advertisements = Advertisement.find(params[:id]) #second line highlighted in red
  end
end
```

Why I can't I view an individual advertisement or see an index of all advertisements like I'm supposed to?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing an index of all the Advertisements when you see the page with just Advertisements at the top, it isn't repeating & printing any because none exist.

Not being able to see just one is because the route defaults to

```
localhost:3000/advertisements/:id
```

So it's trying to lookup an Advertisement with the :id of "index", which most likely doesn't exist.

Try to create an advertisement

Answer (score 0):

You will find that rails is your friend when creating the Routes, Controllers and views you are looking for. Here is the simpliest way to solve you problem:

In terminal cd into your rails program and then:

```
       rails g scaffold advertisement title:string, copy:text, price:integer
       press enter and then rake db:migrate.
```

When you go to localhost:3000/advertisements you on on the index for advertisements localhost:3000/advertisements/[some :id] is the show page for a particular advertisement

additionally in your index view you have to use the block variable you are creating which in this case is advertisement to call the attributes you want on the page:

```
      <%@advertisements.each do |advertisement|%>
      (Which is all the advertisement being looped)

      <%= advertisement.title %>
      <%= advertisement.copy %>
      <%= advertisement.price %>
      <% end%>
```

And you will see a display of individual advertisements with their respective elements

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be outputting anything for each advertisement in your index view and are just looping through the advertisements:

```
<h1>Advertisements</h1>
<% @advertisements.each do |advertisement| %>
<% end %>
```

Inside the loop, you will need to add mark up and ERB that you wish to see for each advertisement.

You can seed your database or create advertisements through the Rails console to test.  As Alfred implies, you should be able to see id=1 at:

```
localhost:3000/advertisements/1
```

Minor point, for show action and view, @advertisement (singular) makes more sense semantically (you are showing a single advertisement).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to Seed some Data.
In you file: db/seeds.rb add:

```
 # Create Advertisements
10.times do 
  Advertisement.create!(
    title: Faker::Internet.domain_name,
    copy: Faker::Company.catch_phrase,
    price: 0
  )
end
```

Then enter this to your terminal: `rake db:seed`

In case you didn't do it, `rake db:migrate`

It should be working now.